# how to convert an array of floats to a byte array?

Tags: c#, arrays, floating-point, byte, converters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert an array of different value types to a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385829/convert-an-array-of-different-value-types-to-a-byte-array)

I have 6 floats and I need to put them in an array of floats and then convert them to bytes. here we go:

```
float x= g.transform.position.x;
float y= g.transform.position.y;
float z= g.transform.position.z;
float alpha = g.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x;
float theta = g.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
float phi =  g.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z;
```

What is the best way to convert an array of floats to a byte array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385829/convert-an-array-of-different-value-types-to-a-byte-array?rq=1

Comment: Can you say a bit more about the goals of this? In particular which endianness you want?

Comment: @CodesInChaos, goal is put floats to an array, array of floats to byte's array and send this byte's array over UDP in big endianness, have you an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If native endianness and LINQ is acceptable, L.B's answer is fine. If you want consistent (little) endianness, use a `BinaryWriter`:

```
using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
using(var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
{
   writer.Write(x);
   writer.Write(y);
   ...
   return stream.ToArray();
}
```

---

If you want to use big endianness you could use the following helper method:

```
byte[] GetBytesBigEndian(float f)
{
  var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(f);
  if(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    Array.Reverse(bytes);
  return bytes;
}

using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
using(var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
{
   writer.Write(GetBytesBigEndian(x));
   writer.Write(GetBytesBigEndian(y));
   ...
   return stream.ToArray();
}
```

If that's too slow, there are also a few `unsafe` tricks to that can speed it up a bit.

Comment: is there a way to use this method without linq?

Comment: @TimTaker Added a version that doesn't depend on LINQ.

Answer (score 2):

```
byte[] data = new float[]{x,y,z,alpha,theta,phi}
                  .SelectMany(f => BitConverter.GetBytes(f)).ToArray();
```

or (depending on the  consumer's computer architecture)

```
byte[] data = new float[]{x,y,z,alpha,theta,phi}
              .SelectMany(f => BitConverter.GetBytes(f).Reverse()).ToArray();
```

you may also want to use `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` to decide which one to choose as @CodesInChaos suggested

Comment: Note that this uses native endianness and is such unsuitable for persistent storage or network communication.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I already suggested serialization technique and gave an example to OP in his previous questions.

Comment: it would be great if there is something to do with a little to big endianness, the above solution shows up an error which says  Type `float[]' does not contain a definition for `SelectMany' and no extension method `SelectMany' of type `float[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @TimTaker **a)** include namespace `System.Linq` **b)** you can also try `BitConverter.GetBytes(f).Reverse()` but i don't think you will need this.

Comment: @L.B You should to check `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` before reversing, even if .net/mono typically only run on little endian platforms.

Comment: I need to do it for unity 3d that doesn't support linq, is there a way to do not use linq?

Comment: @TimTaker see other answers.

Comment: @TimTaker Are you sure unity 3D doesn't support linq-to-objects? A quick search suggests that it does support it.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, oh yes! I didnt look through it too much, any way thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
float[] source = new float[100];
byte[] dest = new byte[source.Length * sizeof(float)];
Buffer.BlockCopy(source, 0, dest, 0, dest.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
var farray = new float[] {12.4f, 12.3f, 4.5f}; // or what ever values you want.
var bArray = new byte[farray.Length];
Buffer.BlockCopy(farray, 0, bArray, 0, bArray.Length);
        foreach (byte value in bArray)
            Console.Write("{0}  ", value);
```

for more information visit [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Comment: is it possible to do this through array list?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cheeky way:

```
float x = 1F;
float y = 2F;
float z = 3F;
float alpha = 4F;
float theta = 5F;
float phi = 6F;
byte[] raw = new byte[6 * sizeof(float)];
fixed (byte* ptr = raw)
{
    float* typed = (float*)ptr;
    typed[0] = x;
    typed[1] = y;
    typed[2] = z;
    typed[3] = alpha;
    typed[4] = theta;
    typed[5] = phi;
}
return raw;
```

Note, however, that it makes assunptions about endianness. You might want to check `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` and reverse each 4-byte chunk if necessary.

Of course, if you can re-use an existing buffer, that is preferable. Same approach - just pass in an existing `byte[]` as a parameter rather than creating a new one each time.

Comment: oh..sorry I can't use unsafe contest