# How to convert array of floats to byte array and send them in endianness over UDP?

Tags: c#, arrays, networking, network-programming

I have an array of floats: `public static List<float> myData = new List<float>();` I need to convert them to big endianness byte array and send them over UDP connection. I've no idea how to do that, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert an array of different value types to a byte array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385829/convert-an-array-of-different-value-types-to-a-byte-array)

Comment: @PeterO. my question is very different, I'm asking about array converting, but not about different types!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:

```
    byte[] array=null;
    List<float> myData = new List<float>();
    myData.Add(43.1f);
    myData.Add(42.1f);
    myData.Add(41.1f);
    myData.Add(40.1f);
    foreach (float a in myData)
       array = BitConverter.GetBytes(a);
    //printing
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
    }
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't see you addressing the endianness of the data in this solution. Am I missing something?

Comment: yes you are right but it can be changed to address the endianness,

Comment: The byte array should have 16 bytes instead of 4

Answer (score 3):

```
int width = sizeof(float);
byte[] data = new byte[myData.Count * width];

for (int i = 0; i < myData.Count; ++i)
{
    byte[] converted = BitConverter.GetBytes(myData[i]);

    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    {
        Array.Reverse(converted);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
    {
        data[i * width + j] = converted[j];
    }

}
```

`data` will be the byte array containing the bit representation of the floats in big endian byte order

To send it with UDP, try something like:

```
Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
IPAddress serverAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(serverAddr, 13);
sock.SendTo(data, endPoint);
```

Comment: You could also do:
<code>
int width = sizeof(float);
<code>
The compiler just substitutes a constant value 4, but it makes the code a little easier to understand.

Comment: @Esailija. thank you for your answer, but while running its shows up: " System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A message sent on a datagram socket was larger than the internal message buffer or some other network limit, or the buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram itself." and prints (3.010, 8.980, 0.500) the data differ from its inputs(1,1,0)

Comment: @TimTaker What is printing those values? Are you just sending 3 floats? (12 bytes of data)?

Comment: those values are axes x,y,z,alpha,theta and phi, they are changes when I movieng the objects with setting a values of the axes

Comment: @TimTaker that is not really relevant. Let me ask another way, how many items are there in the `myData` list when you send it? What is printing out the values?

Comment: @Esailija, I sent to myData 6 floats and according to your code its work properly :D