# C# convert object[ ] into byte[ ], but how to keep byte object as byte?

Tags: c#, data-conversion

I am using [Convert an array of different value types to a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385829/convert-an-array-of-different-value-types-to-a-byte-array) solution for my objects to byte array conversion.

But I have a small issue that causes a big problem.

There are "byte" type of data in mids of object[], I don't know how to keep "byte" as is. I need keep same bytes-length before and after.

I tried add "byte" type into the dictionary like this:

```
private static readonlyDictionary<Type, Func<object, byte[]>> Converters =
    new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, byte[]>>()
{
    { typeof(byte), o => BitConverter.GetBytes((byte) o) },
    { typeof(int), o => BitConverter.GetBytes((int) o) },
    { typeof(UInt16), o => BitConverter.GetBytes((UInt16) o) },
    ...
};
public static void ToBytes(object[] data, byte[] buffer)
{
    int offset = 0;

    foreach (object obj in data)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            // Or do whatever you want
            throw new ArgumentException("Unable to convert null values");
        }
        Func<object, byte[]> converter;
        if (!Converters.TryGetValue(obj.GetType(), out converter))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("No converter for " + obj.GetType());
        }

        byte[] obytes = converter(obj);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(obytes, 0, buffer, offset, obytes.Length);
        offset += obytes.Length;
    }
}
```

there is no syntext complaining, but I traced this code, after the program executed

```
byte[] obytes = converter(obj);
```

the original "byte" becomes byte[2].

What happens here?  How to keep byte value authentic in this solution?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what is happening here.  Can you show the code that creates the object, as well as the code that unpacks it?

Comment: You're getting an array because `GetBytes` returns an array. What exactly are you trying to do here because it's not clear.

Comment: I updated my orginal post.  I know GetBytes returns an array, but I want it return byte[1] for my orignial byte value.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no [`BitConverter.GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.getbytes.aspx) overload that takes a `byte`, so your code:

```
BitConverter.GetBytes((byte) o)
```

Is being implicitly expanded into the nearest match: [`BitConverter.GetBytes(short)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk3sts66.aspx) (`Int16`), resulting in two bytes. All you need to do is return a single-element byte array, e.g. like this:

```
{ typeof(byte), o => new[] { (byte) o } }
```

Comment: Thank you, all.  It works.  I did not understand this lambda thing.